# Translation of 'how do you pronounce 'x''

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions, anglais, usage

I have checked dictionary and thought the correct translation may be this:
*Comment est-ce que tu prononces 'x' ?*

If I want to say 'how do you pronounce this word, which is spelt as :ECRIT'
What is the most appropriate translation?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there are multiple ways of doing this. You could for example use the verbs "prononcer" which is not ambiguous or "dire" which is a bit ambiguous but is understandable depending on the context.

There are also two ways of asking, either by being general and by using the "on" pronoun or by using the "tu" pronoun which directly aims your interlocutor.

1. Comment prononce-t-on 'x' ?
2. Comment dit-on 'x' ?
3. Comment prononces-tu 'x' ?
4. Comment dis-tu 'x' ?

Answer (score 2):

Kii gave a great answer for your first question. The same can be said for the second (that is, there are several ways of translating the second question).

1. Comment prononce-t-on ce mot, qui s'écrit : ECRIT
2. Comment dit-on ce mot, qui est écrit : ECRIT
3. Comment prononces-tu ce mot, qui s'écrit : ECRIT
4. Comment dis-tu ce mot, qui est écrit : ECRIT

I included the passive "qui **est écrit**" as an option, but I think the use of the reflexive "s'écrit" sounds more colloquial.

Comment: Ce que je sais, c'est que les français évitent le passif